# How to sort moment-timezone list?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

I want to show the moment-timezone list in ascending order in a drop-down menu. By default, those are sorted in alphabetical order. But, my requirement is to sort them by GMT in ascending order.

before soring:

```
[
  '(GMT+00:00) Africa/Abidjan',
  '(GMT+00:00) Africa/Accra',
  '(GMT+03:00) Africa/Addis_Ababa',
  '(GMT+01:00) Africa/Algiers',
  '(GMT+03:00) Africa/Asmara',
  '(GMT+03:00) Africa/Asmera',
  '(GMT+00:00) Africa/Bamako',
  '(GMT+01:00) Africa/Bangui',
]
```

after sorting:

```
[
  '(GMT+00:00) Africa/Abidjan',
  '(GMT+00:00) Africa/Accra',
  '(GMT+00:00) Africa/Bamako',
  '(GMT+01:00) Africa/Algiers',
  '(GMT+01:00) Africa/Bangui',
  '(GMT+03:00) Africa/Addis_Ababa',
  '(GMT+03:00) Africa/Asmera',
  '(GMT+03:00) Africa/Asmara',
]
```

Comment: actually, it is a large array. so I didn't give it. anyway now it is edited. I think it make sense now.

Comment: You may want to consider accepting Clément's answer - it naturally makes use of a function that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shorter than yours, Ashik. No need to access the timezone from the array twice

```js
const getTimeZoneList = moment.tz.names()
  .map(t => `(GMT${moment.tz(t).format("Z")}) ${t}`);
const sortByZone = (a,b) => { 
  let [ahh,amm] = a.split("GMT")[1].split(")")[0].split(":"); 
  let [bhh,bmm] = b.split("GMT")[1].split(")")[0].split(":");
  return (+ahh*60+amm) - (+bhh*60+bmm)
};
console.log(getTimeZoneList.sort(sortByZone))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.27/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for the case if we have Moment.js timezone Array of objects(name, value) , or any other Timezone Array of objects with GMT values **HARDCODED** with us and we want to apply sort on them on GMT values.

```
export const Timezones = [
  {
    name: "(GMT-7:00) America/Denver",
    value: "America/Denver"
  },
  {
    name: "(GMT+3:00) Africa/Asmara",
    value: "Africa/Asmara"
  },
  {
    name: "(GMT-11:00) Pacific/Midway",
    value: "Pacific/Midway"
  }
];
```

Then we can sort this Array by

```
timezones.sort( this.compare );

 compare( a, b ) {
     
    var first = a.name.substring(a.name.indexOf('T')+1,a.name.indexOf(")"));
    first.replace(/^"+:"+$/g, '');

    var second = b.name.substring(b.name.indexOf('T')+1,b.name.indexOf(")"));
    first.replace(/^"+:"+$/g, '');

    if ( parseFloat(first) < parseFloat(second) ){
        return -1;
      
    }
    if ( parseFloat(first) > parseFloat(second) ){
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

More simply, there is the `utcOffset()` method that provides the offset compared to GMT:

```js
const result = moment.tz.names()
  .sort((a, b) => moment.tz(a).utcOffset() - moment.tz(b).utcOffset())
  .map(timezone => `(GMT${moment.tz(timezone).format("Z")}) ${timezone}`)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.27/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sorted list by doing this

```js
const timeZones = moment.tz.names();

const getTimeZoneList = () =>
  timeZones.map(
    (t, i) => `(GMT${moment.tz(timeZones[i]).format("Z")}) ${timeZones[i]}`
  );

const sortByGmt = () => {
  const timeZone = getTimeZoneList();
  return timeZone.sort((a, b) => {
    const re = /^\(GMT([+-]\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\).*$/;
    const aOffset = parseFloat(a.replace(re, "$1.$2"));
    const bOffset = parseFloat(b.replace(re, "$1.$2"));
    return aOffset < bOffset ? -1 : aOffset > bOffset ? 1 : 0;
  });
};
console.log(sortByGmt())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.27/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unnecessarily complex. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60078377/295783

Comment: I did not see you answered your own question ;)